# Is it possible to prevent too many async calls with promises?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise

I want to load content into my page with `$.ajax` calls.

New content might be available anytime I scroll. However, there will be many scroll events fired when I scroll my page, and I don't want every one of them to trigger an Ajax call.

I would like to trigger an Ajax call when it is **useful**... Meaning, when there is no Ajax call currently running.

On first load, an Ajax call is immediatly performed. Additionnaly, the completion of a previous Ajax call might give us a reason to perform a new Ajax call.

The code below is a successful experiment : it does exactly what I want. However, I can't shake the feeling that it is not an appropriate writing.

Is there a better way to write this ?

```js
// This variable knows anytime if we are already trying to perform an asynchronous operation and should not ask for another
var lock = false;

// This function tells us if there is something async to do with our page
var thereIsSomethingAsyncToDo = function() {
    // returns true or false
}

// This function performs an asynchronous call, eg. $.ajax()
var doSomethingAsync = function() {
    // returns a Deferred object ?
}

// This function checks if it is the right time to perform an asynchronous operation
var shouldIDoSomething = function() {

    // If the lock is set, then we are already doing something, there is no use in queuing multiple requests that might end doing the same thing
    if (lock)
        return;
    // The lock is not set yet, so we can set it to ensure that every other call will be rejected
    lock = true;

    // Check if there is actually something to do
    if (thereIsSomethingAsyncToDo()) {
        // If there is something to do, chain the resolution of that something with a resolution
        $.when(doSomethingAsync(todo)).done(function() {
            // Release the lock
            lock = false;
            // Check if something else needs to be done
            shouldIDoSomething();
        });
    }
    // If there is nothing to do, simply release the lock
    else {
        lock = false;
    }

};

// Anytime the window is scrolled, we might need to do something
$(window).scroll(function() {
    shouldIDoSomething();
});

// When the page is first loaded we might need to do something
shouldIDoSomething();
```

Comment: Is this intended to be something akin to an infinite scrolling mechanism?

Comment: yes it is infinite scrolling, you caught me red-handed

Comment: Seems like you want some form of debounce and/or throttle. I assume jQuery has this already, or there's a plugin for it, or you can just use another library like lodash. It's rarely worth re-rolling this.

Comment: Reading from http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/ it seems like both debounce and throttle patterns imply delays. I'm not looking to delay anything here, I'm trying to start the new call as soon as the previous one answers. Or is that a bad thing to do ?

Answer (score 1):

I would start by writing your fundamental logic first, i.e. the `doSomethingAsync()` in your example, without thinking about your locking mechanism.

```
async function doSomethingAsync () {
  try {
    if (!thereIsSomethingAsyncToDo()) return;

    const results = await $.ajax('/api/json', { dataType: 'json' });
    // append content to DOM
  } catch (error) {
    // handle error
  }
}
```

After you're finished with that, use the following factory function to prevent the underlying fundamental logic from being triggered again while a previous call is still pending:

```
function lock (fn) {
  let pending = false;

  return async () => {
    if (pending) return;

    try {
      pending = true;
      await fn();
    } finally {
      pending = false;
    }
  };
}

const doSomethingAsyncAndLock = lock(doSomethingAsync);
```

Finally, you want your scroll event to call this new function:

```
$(window).scroll(() => {
  doSomethingAsyncAndLock();
});
```